# ASP.NET Response Headers set Expires value

Tags: asp.net

Whenever I use HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache) to set no-cache, Expires value automatically set to "-1" and it won't change by specifying  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires([Date])

Any Suggestion will be appriciated

Comment: Do you want that setting on just this page or all of your pages? If all,look into web.config

Comment: I have tried adding in web.config but doing this sets the Expires value to "Expires:-1, Fri, 12 Jan 2018 12:02:59 GMT" and it doesn't seems good. I don't know how different browsers behaves in this case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763403/leverage-browser-caching-with-web-config-in-net